# How to enumerate hashtable's key from specific value

Tags: java, collections

For example I have a Hashtable like, and I have a value in Double d=99.22 variable, Here I want to fetch or find the key related to this value.

```
Hashtable<String, Double> balance = new Hashtable<String, Double>();

      balance.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34));
      balance.put("Mahnaz", new Double(123.22));
      balance.put("Ayan", new Double(1378.00));
      balance.put("Daisy", new Double(99.22));
      balance.put("Qadir", new Double(-19.08));

      System.out.println(balance);

      Double d = 99.22;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For one thing, you need to iterate through the hashtable using a loop.

Comment: You basically need to iterate over all the entries... this isn't a good fit for a `Hashtable`, as you're searching by entry rather than key. (Any reason you're using `Hashtable` rather than `HashMap`, btw?) As an aside, it's best not to use `double`/`Double` for currency values - prefer `BigDecimal`, or an integer number of cents/pennies/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Hashtable<String, Double> balance = new Hashtable<String, Double>();

      balance.put("Zara", new Double(3434.34));
      balance.put("Mahnaz", new Double(123.22));
      balance.put("Ayan", new Double(1378.00));
      balance.put("Daisy", new Double(99.22));
      balance.put("Qadir", new Double(-19.08));

      System.out.println(balance);
      Double d = 99.22;



     String key=null;
        for(Map.Entry entry: balance.entrySet()){
          if(d.equals(entry.getValue())){
              key = (String) entry.getKey();
              break;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("got key from value in hashtable key:  "+ key +" value: " + d);
```

I hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you parametrize entry?

Comment: Because I want to use the entry.getValue() method so I used Entry Interface

Comment: I mean using `Entry<String, Double>` to skip casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after the code snippet you have mentioned in the post:

```js
    for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e : balance.entrySet()){
        if(e.getValue()== d.doubleValue()){
            System.out.println(e.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for(Entry<String, Double> e : balance.entrySet())` is much better